# Custom SSIS Package fails to load vs 2019 sql server 2016

Tags: ssis

I tried to develop  a simple Task but encountred this error
[image: Here is the error message]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

1. Download and install “SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio” the
   last version
2. Repair SQL Server along with client components. This can be done by
   choosing option in SQL Setup

[image]